# Setting Tags in JSON Order Softlayer API Python

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I noticed there's a setTags() method in the api but is there a way to add it to the json order during the ordering process? I can't find any information on it in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible to se the tags at order time take a look at this example:

https://softlayer.github.io/python/create_vsi_options/

I hope it helps

Regards

Comment: Awesome thank you Nelson. I have another quick question:
We encountered an issue where we put the VLAN ID in the json order but when the VM's were provisioned 4/5 were put into different vlans. Is this due to space issues? Is there a way to shoot back an error if they can't be placed in the VLAN's that I specified in the JSON? Wondering if there's a way to stop vlan span?

Comment: Yep it is probably because space, the API Will not trow any error if there is not enough space at provisioning time softlayer Will try to assign another VLAN if there is not available vlans the order Will not be provisioned and a sofltlayer's employee Will contact you. If you want to change the VLAN in a provisioned server you need to submit a ticket. If you want to check if a vlan has space before ordering you need to check if there are free slots, I think there are quesrions about that stackoverdlow please take a link to those questions