# Softlayer Virtual Guest - Invalid value provided for tags

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure, virtual-server

I am setting the tag value for a Virtual Guest with the following method

```
vs_object.setTags
```

I am setting the tag value with ( ) in it. And its giving error that

```
XMLRPC::FaultException: Invalid value provided for 'tags'. Invalid tag names:Key:121 software (sd log)
```

When I remove the curly bracket the set tag method works. Please let me know which  all special characters are not allowed while setting the tag. 
This [link](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/setTags/) did not provide much information about the allowed characters in tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here there is information about allowed values in tags
[call API method SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/setTags.json failed due to 'Invalid tag names'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47196477/call-api-method-softlayer-virtual-guest-settags-json-failed-due-to-invalid-tag)

> the characters permitted are A-Z, 0-9, whitespace, _ (underscore), -
>   (hypen), . (period), and : (colon),

You can also review [Softlayer : tagging device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42945216/softlayer-tagging-device) to know more about tags